# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while decrypting using CCDecrypt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, encryption

I am trying to decrypt data in ios which was encrypted in Java. Following is the code:

```
+(NSString*) decryptData:(NSString*) data:( NSData*) passKey {

    NSString * strKey = [Base64Util encodeBase64WithData:passKey];
    NSLog( @" decryption key: %@" ,strKey);

    //decrypt `data
    NSData * nsData = [Base64Util decodeBase64WithString:data];
    NSLog(@"here 1: %@",nsData);

    size_t numOfBytesDecrypted;
    size_t bufferSize = nsData.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    NSMutableData * buffer = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:bufferSize];
    CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCOptionECBMode , derivedKey.bytes, derivedKey.length, Nil , passCodeData.bytes, passCodeData.length, buffer. mutableBytes, bufferSize, &numOfBytesDecrypted);

    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer. mutableBytes length :numOfBytesDecrypted];
```

}

But when the function CCCrypt executes, it throws up an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2. I have ARC enabled. I am unable to find the cause of the error. An help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `derivedKey` ivar, where did it come from? Also, what is the value of `decryptData` argument? Isn't it `data`? Could you please correct your question as appropriate so we could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really silly of me.

The second parameter should be `kCCAlgorithmAES128`